# Where is the Guest account registry hive stored when its logged off?

Tags: windows, registry

I need to make changes to the Windows built-in Guest account registry hive when the user is logged off. Does anyone know where it's stored?

Comment: Presumably, `c:\users\guest\ntuser.dat`, same as any other account.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, is there an API to parse/read it?

Comment: Much appreciated! I didn't know that such functionality existed. So I'm assuming that once I open it with RegLoadKey and apply the change, I can then do RegSaveKey to save it back, so that the next time when that user logs in the change will take effect, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry hive for the guest account will normally be in `c:\users\guest\ntuser.dat`, the same as any other account.  (Note that in some cases the profile might have a different name, e.g., if there is a domain guest user and that profile was created first.  Also, for Windows XP and earlier, the path is `c:\documents and settings\guest\ntuser.dat`.)

You can load this hive into the registry using [RegLoadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then manipulate it using the normal registry functions.

When you're finished with it, use [RegUnLoadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  This will make sure all your changes are saved, although this will also happen automatically when the machine shuts down.  It will also release the lock on the file so that the account can log in again.

(I'm not sure what will happen if someone tries to log in while you've manually loaded the user hive.  I recommend you disable the account before loading the hive and re-enable it after unloading.)

Comment: Much appreciated. I'll mark it as an answer (although I haven't tested it yet. It will take me some time to do so.)